# How to properly test Custom Metadata in Apex?

Tags: apex, metadata, custom-metadata

I'm having some trouble trying to test this methods:

```
public class SendingSAPServices {
    
    public static final String SERVICE_SYNC_CLIENTE = 'SYNC_CLIENTE';
    public static final String SERVICE_SYNC_SEDE = 'SYNC_SEDE';
    public static final String SERVICE_SYNC_MATERIAL = 'SYNC_MATERIAL';
    public static final String SERVICE_SYNC_PEDIDO = 'SYNC_PEDIDO';
   
    public static void saveBy(List<Account> accounts){   
        
        List<SendingSAP__c> sendingsToInsert = new List<SendingSAP__c>();
        ConfiguracionServiceSAP__mdt confService = getConfiguracionService(SERVICE_SYNC_CLIENTE);
        //accounts.get(0).addError('error 1: ' + confService);
        if(confService != null){
            for(Account account : accounts){
                SendingSAP__c sending = getNew(confService, 'Account__c', account);
                sending.Request__c = SAPServices.getClienteSAPToSync(account);
                sendingsToInsert.add(sending);
            }
            insert sendingsToInsert;
            setLastSendingSAP(sendingsToInsert, accounts, 'Account__c');
        }
    }
    
    public static void saveBy(List<Asset> assets){
        List<SendingSAP__c> sendingsToInsert = new List<SendingSAP__c>();
        ConfiguracionServiceSAP__mdt confService = getConfiguracionService(SERVICE_SYNC_SEDE);
        for(Asset asset : assets){
            SendingSAP__c sending = getNew(confService, 'Sede__c', asset);
            sending.Request__c = SAPServices.getSedeSAPToSync(asset);
            sendingsToInsert.add(sending);
        }
        insert sendingsToInsert;
        setLastSendingSAP(sendingsToInsert, assets, 'Sede__c');
    }
```

Problem is this

> if(confService != null)

is returning null so the test method is stopping there and the rest is highlighted in red, you know.

This is the test class I've written:

```
@isTest
public class AccountTriggerHandlerTest {
    
    @testSetup public static void testSetup(){
        


        Account firstAccount = new Account();
        firstAccount.Name = 'First Account';
        firstAccount.SAPStatus__c = 'Pending SAP';
        firstAccount.CodigoCliente__c = '26000000';
        firstAccount.IsNew__c = true;
        insert firstAccount;
        
        Account secondAccount = new Account();
        secondAccount.Name = 'Second Account';
        secondAccount.SAPStatus__c = 'New';
        secondAccount.CodigoCliente__c = '66000000';
        secondAccount.IsNew__c = false;
        insert secondAccount;
    }
    
    @isTest public static void testAccount(){
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        ConfiguracionServiceSAP__mdt confService = [SELECT DeveloperName, MasterLabel, ServiceName__c 
                                                    FROM ConfiguracionServiceSAP__mdt 
                                                    WHERE ServiceName__c  = 'SYNC_CLIENTE' 
                                                    AND DeveloperName = 'DESARROLLO_SYN_CLIENTE'];
        
        Account firstAcc = [SELECT Name from Account WHERE Name = 'First Account'];
        Account secondAcc = [SELECT Name from Account WHERE Name = 'Second Account'];
        secondAcc.SAPStatus__c = 'Pending SAP';
        update secondAcc;
        
        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

I've tried the query in the query editor and it's returning the expected value so I can't figure out why it's NULL when running the test.

Would appreaciate some help !!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection is our usual approach and there are many ways to do it. One example:

```
public with sharing class MyMetadata
{
    static final Map<String, MyMetadata__mdt> mappings;
    static
    {
        mappings = new Map<String, MyMetadata__mdt>();
        for (MyMetadata__mdt mapping : [/*query*/])
            mappings.put(mapping.Name, mapping);
    }
    @TestVisible static void setMock(MyMetadata__mdt mapping)
    {
        mappings.put(mapping.Name, mapping);
    }
    public static MyMetadata__mdt get(String name)
    {
        return mappings.get(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and the answer, I'll check it out and accept it as the best if suitable :D

Comment: HI Adrian ... could you please explain me a bit more, I don't really understand what are you doing here .... Where am I supposed to create the MyMetadata class and how should I call it ?? Im super new with this configurations ... Thanks a looooooot

Comment: In this example it would be top level. You would just call `MyMetadata.get(SERVICE_SYNC_CLIENTE)`. Then in your test you would call `MyMetadata.setMock(new MyMetadata__mdt(Name=MyService.SERVICE_SYNC_CLIENTE))`.

Comment: Look, I've edited the question so you can see the real thing: So do I need to refactor the SendingSAPServices class (this is the class I need to test) to look more like the code you posted ??